# how to add pagination to custom featured post for blogger

Tags: blogger

I want to add featured post with numbered pagination to my blogger blog. Like pagination[image: xxx] I got a script for this but I am not able to modify this script for numbered pagination. 
below is the script.

```
<script>
var numposts = 5;
var showpostthumbnails = true;
var displaymore = true;
var displayseparator = false;
var showcommentnum = false;
var showpostdate = true;
var showpostsummary = true;
var numchars = 70;

var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = 'img.recent_thumb {width: 90px;height: 70px;float: left; margin-right: 10px;} .recent_posts_with_thumbs {float: left;width: 100%;min-height: 70px;margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;padding: 0;font-size:12px;list-style-type:none;} ul.recent_posts_with_thumbs li {padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;min-height:65px;} .recent_posts_with_thumbs a {text-decoration:none;} .recent_posts_with_thumbs strong {font-size:10px;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
document.getElementById('someElementId').className = 'cssClass';

function showrecentpostswiththumbs(json) {
document.write('<ul class="recent_posts_with_thumbs">');
for (var i = 0; i < numposts; i++) {
    var entry = json.feed.entry[i];
    var posttitle = entry.title.$t;
    var posturl;
    if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
    for (var k = 0; k < entry.link.length; k++) {
        if (entry.link[k].rel == 'replies' && entry.link[k].type == 'text/html') {
            var commenttext = entry.link[k].title;
            var commenturl = entry.link[k].href;
        }
        if (entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
            posturl = entry.link[k].href;
            break;
        }
    }
    var thumburl;
    try {
        thumburl = entry.media$thumbnail.url;
    } catch (error) {
        s = entry.content.$t;
        a = s.indexOf("<img");
        b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
        c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
        d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
        if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
            thumburl = d;
        } else thumburl = 'http://www.webaholic.co.in/other/no-image.jpg';
    }
    var postdate = entry.published.$t;
    var cdyear = postdate.substring(0, 4);
    var cdmonth = postdate.substring(5, 7);
    var cdday = postdate.substring(8, 10);
    var monthnames = new Array();
    monthnames[1] = "Jan";
    monthnames[2] = "Feb";
    monthnames[3] = "Mar";
    monthnames[4] = "Apr";
    monthnames[5] = "May";
    monthnames[6] = "Jun";
    monthnames[7] = "Jul";
    monthnames[8] = "Aug";
    monthnames[9] = "Sep";
    monthnames[10] = "Oct";
    monthnames[11] = "Nov";
    monthnames[12] = "Dec";
    document.write('<li class="clearfix">');
    if (showpostthumbnails == true) document.write('<img class="recent_thumb" src="' + thumburl + '"/>');
    document.write('<b><a href="' + posturl + '" target ="_top">' + posttitle + '</a></b><br>');
    if ("content" in entry) {
        var postcontent = entry.content.$t;
    } else if ("summary" in entry) {
        var postcontent = entry.summary.$t;
    } else var postcontent = "";
    var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
    postcontent = postcontent.replace(re, "");
    if (showpostsummary == true) {
        if (postcontent.length < numchars) {
            document.write('<i>');
            document.write(postcontent);
            document.write('</i>');
        } else {
            document.write('<i>');
            postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, numchars);
            var quoteEnd = postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");
            postcontent = postcontent.substring(0, quoteEnd);
            document.write(postcontent + '...');
            document.write('</i>');
        }
    }
    var towrite = '';
    var flag = 0;
    document.write('<br><strong>');
    if (showpostdate == true) {
        towrite = towrite + monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth, 10)] + '-' + cdday + ' - ' + cdyear;
        flag = 1;
    }
    if (showcommentnum == true) {
        if (flag == 1) {
            towrite = towrite + ' | ';
        }
        if (commenttext == '1 Comments') commenttext = '1 Comment';
        if (commenttext == '0 Comments') commenttext = 'No Comments';
        commenttext = '<a href="' + commenturl + '" target ="_top">' + commenttext + '</a>';
        towrite = towrite + commenttext;
        flag = 1;;
    }
    if (displaymore == true) {
        if (flag == 1) towrite = towrite + ' | ';
        towrite = towrite + '<a href="' + posturl + '" class="url" target ="_top">More -></a>';
        flag = 1;;
    }
    document.write(towrite);
    document.write('</strong></li>');
    if (displayseparator == true) if (i != (numposts - 1)) document.write('<hr size=0.5>');
}
document.write('</ul>');
}
</script>
<script src='/feeds/posts/default/-/featured?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showrecentpostswiththumbs'></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample script for that would look like -

```js
    var syb_numposts = 3;
    var syb_labelname = "apps";
    var syb_pagetoshow = 4;
    var syb_showpostthumbnails = true;
    var syb_displaymore = true;
    var syb_displayseparator = true;
    var syb_showcommentnum = false;
    var syb_showpostdate = true;
    var syb_showpostsummary = true;
    var syb_numchars = 70;

    var syb_style = document.createElement('style');
    syb_style.type = 'text/css';
    syb_style.innerHTML =
        'a.syb_page-link {cursor: pointer;}.syb_pagination li {display: inline-block; margin: 10px 5px 10px;}img.syb_recent_thumb {width: 90px;height: 70px;float: left; margin-right: 10px;} .syb_recent_posts_with_thumbs {float: left;width: 100%;min-height: 70px;margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;padding: 0;font-size:12px;list-style-type:none;} ul.syb_recent_posts_with_thumbs li {padding-bottom:5px;padding-top:5px;min-height:65px;} .syb_recent_posts_with_thumbs a {text-decoration:none;} .syb_recent_posts_with_thumbs strong {font-size:10px;}';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(syb_style);

    function syb_showrecentpostswiththumbs(json) {
        var syb_FullContainer = document.createElement("div");
        var syb_ListContainer = document.createElement("ul");
        syb_ListContainer.className = 'syb_recent_posts_with_thumbs';

        for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
            var syb_entry = json.feed.entry[i];
            var syb_posttitle = syb_entry.title.$t;
            var syb_posturl;
            if (i == json.feed.entry.length) break;
            for (var k = 0; k < syb_entry.link.length; k++) {
                if (syb_entry.link[k].rel == 'replies' && syb_entry.link[k].type ==
                    'text/html') {
                    var syb_commenttext = syb_entry.link[k].title;
                    var syb_commenturl = syb_entry.link[k].href;
                }
                if (syb_entry.link[k].rel == 'alternate') {
                    syb_posturl = syb_entry.link[k].href;
                    break;
                }
            }
            var syb_thumburl;
            try {
                syb_thumburl = syb_entry.media$thumbnail.url;
            } catch (error) {
                s = syb_entry.summary.$t;
                a = s.indexOf("<img");
                b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
                c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
                d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
                if ((a != -1) && (b != -1) && (c != -1) && (d != "")) {
                    syb_thumburl = d;
                } else syb_thumburl =
                    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/No_image_available.svg/300px-No_image_available.svg.png';
            }
            var syb_postdate = syb_entry.published.$t;
            var syb_cdyear = syb_postdate.substring(0, 4);
            var syb_cdmonth = syb_postdate.substring(5, 7);
            var syb_cdday = syb_postdate.substring(8, 10);
            var syb_monthnames = new Array();
            syb_monthnames[1] = "Jan";
            syb_monthnames[2] = "Feb";
            syb_monthnames[3] = "Mar";
            syb_monthnames[4] = "Apr";
            syb_monthnames[5] = "May";
            syb_monthnames[6] = "Jun";
            syb_monthnames[7] = "Jul";
            syb_monthnames[8] = "Aug";
            syb_monthnames[9] = "Sep";
            syb_monthnames[10] = "Oct";
            syb_monthnames[11] = "Nov";
            syb_monthnames[12] = "Dec";

            var syb_ItemContainer = document.createElement("li");
            syb_ItemContainer.className = 'clearfix';

            if (syb_showpostthumbnails == true){
            var syb_ItemImageLink = document.createElement("a");
            syb_ItemImageLink.setAttribute("href", syb_posturl);
            var syb_ItemImage = document.createElement("img");
            syb_ItemImage.className = 'syb_recent_thumb';
            syb_ItemImage.setAttribute("src", syb_thumburl);
            syb_ItemImageLink.appendChild(syb_ItemImage);

            }

            var syb_ItemLinkContainer = document.createElement("b");
            var syb_ItemLink = document.createElement("a");
            syb_ItemLink.setAttribute("href", syb_posturl);
            var syb_ItemLinkText = document.createTextNode(syb_posttitle);


            syb_ItemLink.appendChild(syb_ItemLinkText);
            syb_ItemLinkContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemLink);
            
            var syb_ItemContainerBreak = document.createElement('br');

            
            if ("content" in syb_entry) {
                var syb_postcontent = syb_entry.content.$t;
            } else if ("summary" in syb_entry) {
                var syb_postcontent = syb_entry.summary.$t;
            } else var syb_postcontent = "";
            var re = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
            syb_postcontent = syb_postcontent.replace(re, "");
            var syb_ItemLinkSummaryContainer = document.createElement("i");
            if (syb_showpostsummary == true) {
                if (syb_postcontent.length < syb_numchars) {
                    var syb_ItemLinkSummary = document.createTextNode(syb_postcontent);
                    syb_ItemLinkSummaryContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemLinkSummary);
                } else {
                    syb_postcontent = syb_postcontent.substring(0, syb_numchars);
                    var quoteEnd = syb_postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");
                    syb_postcontent = syb_postcontent.substring(0, quoteEnd);
                    var syb_ItemLinkSummary = document.createTextNode(syb_postcontent + "...");
                    syb_ItemLinkSummaryContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemLinkSummary);
                }
            }
            var syb_towrite = '';
            var syb_flag = 0;
            var syb_ItemContainerMetaDataContainer = document.createElement('strong');
            if (syb_showpostdate == true) {
                syb_towrite = syb_monthnames[parseInt(syb_cdmonth, 10)] + '-' +
                    syb_cdday + ' - ' + syb_cdyear;
                syb_flag = 1;
            var syb_ItemContainerMetaDataDateContainer = document.createElement('span');
            var ItemContainerMetaDataDate = document.createTextNode(syb_towrite);
            syb_ItemContainerMetaDataDateContainer.appendChild(ItemContainerMetaDataDate);
            syb_ItemContainerMetaDataContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemContainerMetaDataDateContainer);

            }
            if (syb_showcommentnum == true) {
                
                if (syb_commenttext == '1 Comments') syb_commenttext = '1 Comment';
                if (syb_commenttext == '0 Comments') syb_commenttext = 'No Comments';

                var syb_ItemCommentLink = document.createElement("a");
                syb_ItemCommentLink.setAttribute("href", syb_commenturl);
                if (syb_flag == 1) {
                var syb_ItemCommentLinkText = document.createTextNode(" | " + syb_commenttext);
                } else {
                var syb_ItemCommentLinkText = document.createTextNode(syb_commenttext);
                }
                syb_ItemCommentLink.appendChild(syb_ItemCommentLinkText);

                syb_flag = 1;
                syb_ItemContainerMetaDataContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemCommentLink);

            }
            if (syb_displaymore == true) {

                var syb_ItemReadMoreLink = document.createElement("a");
                syb_ItemReadMoreLink.setAttribute("href", syb_posturl);

                if (syb_flag == 1) {
                var syb_ItemReadMoreText = document.createTextNode(" | More ->");
                } else {
                var syb_ItemReadMoreText = document.createTextNode("More ->");
                }
                syb_ItemReadMoreLink.appendChild(syb_ItemReadMoreText);
                syb_flag = 1;
                syb_ItemContainerMetaDataContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemReadMoreLink);

            }
            
            syb_ItemContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemImageLink);
            syb_ItemContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemLinkContainer);
            syb_ItemContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemContainerBreak);
            syb_ItemContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemLinkSummaryContainer);
            syb_ItemContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemContainerBreak);
            syb_ItemContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemContainerMetaDataContainer);

            if (syb_displayseparator == true){
                var syb_ItemSeperator = document.createElement("hr");
                syb_ItemSeperator.style.clear = 'both';
                syb_ItemContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemSeperator);

            }

            syb_ListContainer.appendChild(syb_ItemContainer);
            syb_FullContainer.appendChild(syb_ListContainer);
        }
        
        syb_numberofpages = Math.ceil(json.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t / json.feed.openSearch$itemsPerPage.$t);
        var syb_pagestoshow = (syb_pagetoshow <= syb_numberofpages)?syb_pagetoshow:syb_numberofpages;

        var syb_PaginationContainer = document.createElement("div");
        syb_PaginationContainer.className = 'syb_pagination';
        var syb_PageContainer = document.createElement("ul");

        for (g = 1; g <= syb_pagestoshow; g++) {
        var syb_SinglePage = document.createElement("li");
        var syb_SinglePageLink = document.createElement("a");
        syb_SinglePageLink.setAttribute("data-href", "#");
        syb_SinglePageLink.className = 'syb_page-link';
        var syb_SinglePageLinkText = document.createTextNode(g);
        syb_SinglePageLink.appendChild(syb_SinglePageLinkText);
        syb_SinglePage.appendChild(syb_SinglePageLink);
        syb_PageContainer.appendChild(syb_SinglePage);

        }

        syb_PaginationContainer.appendChild(syb_PageContainer);
        syb_FullContainer.appendChild(syb_PaginationContainer);
        document.querySelector('.syb_featuredpostlist').innerHTML = '';
        document.querySelector('.syb_featuredpostlist').appendChild(syb_FullContainer);

        for (j = 0; j < document.querySelectorAll('a.syb_page-link').length; j++)(function(j) {
            document.querySelectorAll('a.syb_page-link')[j].onclick = function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                syb_PaginationScript = document.createElement('script');
                syb_PaginationScript.src = "https://webmasters.googleblog.com/feeds/posts/summary/-/" + syb_labelname + "?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + syb_numposts + "&start-index=" + ((j*syb_numposts)+1) + "&callback=syb_showrecentpostswiththumbs";
                var syb_PaginationScriptPosition = document.querySelector('.syb_featuredpostlist');
                syb_PaginationScriptPosition.parentNode.insertBefore(syb_PaginationScript, syb_PaginationScriptPosition);
            };
        })(j);
    }

    var syb_ScriptLoad = document.createElement('script');
    syb_ScriptLoad.src = "https://webmasters.googleblog.com/feeds/posts/summary/-/" + syb_labelname + "?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&max-results=" + syb_numposts + "&callback=syb_showrecentpostswiththumbs";
    var syb_ScriptPosition = document.querySelector('.syb_featuredpostlist');
    syb_ScriptPosition.parentNode.insertBefore(syb_ScriptLoad, syb_ScriptPosition);
```

```html
<div class='syb_featuredpostlist'></div>
```

To change the label from which the posts are being fetched, change the value of the variable `syb_labelname` . Also change `https://webmasters.googleblog.com/` with your own Blog URL.

Answer (score 0):

I want to adjust the size of the thumbnails because they look too faded in Blogger blog with edit method

```js
function showrecentpostswiththumbs(_0x92bcx2) {
    document.write("<ul class=\"recent_posts_with_thumbs\">");
    for (var _0x92bcx3 = 0; _0x92bcx3 < numposts; _0x92bcx3++) {
        var _0x92bcx4 = _0x92bcx2.feed.entry[_0x92bcx3];
        var _0x92bcx5 = _0x92bcx4.title["$t"];
        var _0x92bcx6;
        if (_0x92bcx3 == _0x92bcx2.feed.entry.length) {
            break
        };
        for (var _0x92bcx7 = 0; _0x92bcx7 < _0x92bcx4.link.length; _0x92bcx7++) {
            if ("replies" == _0x92bcx4.link[_0x92bcx7].rel && "text/html" == _0x92bcx4.link[_0x92bcx7].type) {
                var _0x92bcx8 = _0x92bcx4.link[_0x92bcx7].title;
                var _0x92bcx9 = _0x92bcx4.link[_0x92bcx7].href
            };
            if ("alternate" == _0x92bcx4.link[_0x92bcx7].rel) {
                _0x92bcx6 = _0x92bcx4.link[_0x92bcx7].href;
                break
            }
        };
        var _0x92bcxa;
        try {
            _0x92bcxa = _0x92bcx4["media$thumbnail"].url
        } catch (n) {
            s = _0x92bcx4.content["$t"];
            a = s.indexOf("<img");
            b = s.indexOf("src=\"", a);
            c = s.indexOf("\"", b + 5);
            d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5);
            if (a != -1 && b != -1 && c != -1 && "" != d) {
                _0x92bcxa = d
            } else {
                _0x92bcxa = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRwsQvVCjZbRyFTLRNyDmT1a1boZV"
            }
        };
        var _0x92bcxb = _0x92bcx4.published["$t"];
        var _0x92bcxc = _0x92bcxb.substring(0, 4);
        var _0x92bcxd = _0x92bcxb.substring(5, 7);
        var _0x92bcxe = _0x92bcxb.substring(8, 10);
        var _0x92bcxf = new Array();
        _0x92bcxf[1] = "Jan";
        _0x92bcxf[2] = "Feb";
        _0x92bcxf[3] = "Mar";
        _0x92bcxf[4] = "Apr";
        _0x92bcxf[5] = "May";
        _0x92bcxf[6] = "Jun";
        _0x92bcxf[7] = "Jul";
        _0x92bcxf[8] = "Aug";
        _0x92bcxf[9] = "Sep";
        _0x92bcxf[10] = "Oct";
        _0x92bcxf[11] = "Nov";
        _0x92bcxf[12] = "Dec";
        document.write("<li class=\"recent-box\">");
        if (true == showpostthumbnails) {
            document.write("<img class=\"recent_thumb\" src=\"" + _0x92bcxa + "\"/>")
        };
        document.write("<div class=\"label_title\"><a href=\"" + _0x92bcx6 + "\" target =\"_top\">" + _0x92bcx5 + "</a></div>");
        var _0x92bcx10 = "";
        var _0x92bcx11 = 0;
        document.write("");
        if (true == showpostdate) {
            _0x92bcx10 = _0x92bcx10 + _0x92bcxf[parseInt(_0x92bcxd, 10)] + "-" + _0x92bcxe + " - " + _0x92bcxc;
            _0x92bcx11 = 1
        };
        if (true == displaymore) {
            if (1 == _0x92bcx11) {
                _0x92bcx10 += ""
            };
            _0x92bcx10 = _0x92bcx10 + "<div class=\"recent-com\"> <a href=\"" + _0x92bcx6 + "\" target =\"_top\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"fa fa-download\"></i> Download</a></div>";
            _0x92bcx11 = 1
        };
        document.write(_0x92bcx10);
        document.write("</li>")
    };
    document.write("</ul>")
};
```